# how to set to NULL all the filestream varbinary(max) fields?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, filestream

I need to create a test database out of a huge database where the most data is contained as filestream data.

I need to test not filestream related data, so what I'd like to do is to remove the varbinary(max) info.

These are the fields I have in my FILE_REPOSITORY_TABLE table:

```
[ID_FILE] [int] NOT NULL,
[FILE_DATA] [varbinary](max) FILESTREAM  NULL,
[GUID] [uniqueidentifier] ROWGUIDCOL  NOT NULL
```

What I tried to do is

```
Update FILE_REPOSITORY_TABLE
SET FILE = NULL
```

I was expecting this to delete the files too, but it didn't happen.

I cannot delete the records, since ID_FILE has FK links. (when deleting records from a table containing filestream data also the related files are deleted). I also tried to do a backup anyway but the file size was big, even if the table is full of NULLs.

How can I do?

Final note: my goal is to have a 500MB backup instead of a 10GB one (I have 9,5 GB of docs). THis is only for testing purposes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file data is reclaimed through a garbage collection process, rather then being removed immediately. [Related blog post](http://blogs.technet.com/b/sqlman/archive/2009/03/12/sql-server-2008-filestream-data-delete-statement.aspx), so you might need to force checkpointing to occur.

Comment: Yes... The garbage collector... I tried with CHECKPOINT, and also with CHECKPOINT 100 (to force the checkpoint to occur in 100 seconds). But no luck. The garbage collector seems to proceed at his own pace... I rigth click on the FIlestream folder and read the number of files (in properties), every few seconds a few docs are deleted. Anyway thanks for the answer, I will ask now again a more specific answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650387/how-to-force-the-filestream-garbage-collector-to-complete-its-work-with-the-highe

Comment: Additional note: I accept this an answer because it helped me understanding that the problem was related to the Garbage collector.